# ¿Cómo mover el último elemento de un array a otro?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer un curso de nivelación para acceder a un curso de programación. Este ejercicio me tiene atascada:

> Declará una función trasladar, que tome dos arrays, saque el último elemento del primero y lo agregue al segundo.

Ejemplo:

```
let unArray = [1, 2, 3];
let otroArray = [4, 5];

trasladar(unArray, otroArray);

unArray //debería ser [1, 2]
otroArray //debería ser [4, 5, 3]
```

Mi respuesta fue esta:

```
function trasladar (unArray,otroArray){
    let unArray=[1,2,];
    let array2=unArray.pop()
    let otroArray=[3,4];
    otroArray.push(array2)
    
}
```

¿Por qué está mal y qué me estoy saltando?

Comment: Ya hay respuestas inteligentes y bastante acertadas a esta pregunta, asi que solo te dire una cosa: te felicito por crear una buena pregunta!, siendo una nueva usuaria es muy poco frecuente encontrarte con buenas preguntas, pues estas normalmente no se adhieren a las reglas de la comunidad, en este caso haz creado una pregunta que es valida, tiene argumentos y muestra lo que haz intentado de manera bien formateada, muy bien Antonela!.

Comment: muchas gracias Riven!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La idea de la función es que los parámetros `unArray` y `otroArray` vengan con valores desde el exterior (al momento de llamarlos), por lo que la función es más sencilla aún, quitándole las declaraciones de variable internas:

```
function trasladar (unArray,otroArray){
  let array2=unArray.pop()
  otroArray.push(array2)
}
```

Luego esta se puede llamar con los valores deseados:

```
trasladar( [1,2] , [2,5,7] )
```

Answer (score 3):

- No utilices los nombres de parámetros para igualarlos con vectores
- Estos parámetros te servirán para usarlos dentro de la función y estructurar la lógica a desarrollar cuando el usuario invoque a la función y pase los argumentos con los cuales se sustituirán los parámetros
- Los vectores son declarados por fuera de la función y pasados como argumentos cuando invocas a la función por su nombre, ya que de lo contrario obtendrás como error un aviso similar a este:

> "SyntaxError: Identifier 'unArray' has already been declared

- Debes retornar el vector que se le agregó un nuevo elemento o cuando trates de imprimir el resultado este será undefined
- Trata de usar nombres de variables mas descriptivos

```js
    function trasladar (unArray,otroArray) {
        //let unArray=[1,2,]; eliminar
        let elementoMovible =unArray.pop();
        //let otroArray=[3,4]; eliminar
        otroArray.push(elementoMovible);
        return otroArray;
    }
    
    let unArray = [1, 2, 3];
    let otroArray = [4, 5];
    
    console.log(trasladar(unArray, otroArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

seria de esta manera.

```
var unArray = [1, 2, 3];
var otroArray = [4, 5];

trasladar(unArray, otroArray);

console.log(unArray) //debería ser [1, 2]
console.log(otroArray) //debería ser [4, 5, 3]" 

function trasladar (Array1,Array2){

    let valor = Array1[Array1.length - 1];
    Array1.pop();

    Array2.push(valor)
    
}
```

El detalle era en la función de como realizar el proceso de extraer y agregar.
Y para trabajar con Arreglos son pop y push.

y para resumir más el código podríamos poner de esta manera la agregación.

```
var unArray = [1, 2, 3];
var otroArray = [4, 5];

trasladar(unArray, otroArray);

console.log(unArray) //debería ser [1, 2]
console.log(otroArray) //debería ser [4, 5, 3]" 

function trasladar (Array1,Array2){
    Array2.push(Array1.pop())    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Después de revisar tu código y ver los resultados arrojados por la consola encontré este error: El error que tienes, es que estás declarando variables innecesarias dentro de tu función principal. Básicamente quedaría así:

```
function trasladar (unArray,otroArray){
    let array2 = unArray.pop()
    otroArray.push(array2)    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function trasladar(unArray, otroArray) {
  const newArray = [...otroArray] //creo una copia 
  const ultimo = unArray[unArray.length -1] ; //ultimo num del primer array
  otroArray.push(ultimo) //lo agrego al segundo
}

//Arrow Function

const trasladar = (unArray, otroArray) => {
  const newArray = [...otroArray] //creo una copia 
  const ultimo = unArray[unArray.length -1]; //ultimo num del primer array
  newArray.push(ultimo) //lo agrego al segundo

  return newArray
}
```

Comment: La pregunta dice "¿por qué está mal y qué me estoy saltando?" No pide código para que le resuelvan el enunciado. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.